# How to avoid switch case while implementing functionality similar to reddits posts sort

Tags: c#, design-patterns, switch-statement

I have interface ISortPostsStrategy for all sorting strategies (SortPostsByTop, SortPostsByBest, SortPostsByNew) I need sorting with option to choose timeframe for all sorting types without one and I tried using strategy pattern but the problem is that ISortPostsStrategy have timeframe parameter that SortPostByNew dont need and it end up being unused.

```
public interface ISortPostsStrategy
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId, DateTime startDate);
}


public class SortPostsByNew : ISortPostsStrategy
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public SortPostsByNew(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId, DateTime startDate)
    {
        var dbPosts = await this.unitOfWork.Posts.GetBySubcribedUserOrderedByNewAsync(userId);
        return dbPosts;
    }
}

public class SortPostsByBest : ISortPostsStrategy
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public SortPostsByBest(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId, DateTime startDate)
    {
        var dbPosts = await this.unitOfWork.Posts.GetBySubscribedUserOrderedByBestAsync(userId, startDate);
        return dbPosts;
    }
}
```

This is the switch case Im trying to avoid before strategy patttern

```
IEnumerable<Post> dbPosts = null;

        if (sortType == PostSortType.New)
        {
            dbPosts = await this.redditCloneUnitOfWork.Posts
                .GetBySubcribedUserOrderedByNewAsync(dbUser.Id);
        }
        else if (sortType == PostSortType.Top)
        {
            dbPosts = await this.redditCloneUnitOfWork.Posts
                .GetBySubcribedUserOrderedByTopAsync(dbUser.Id, startDate);
        }
        else if (sortType == PostSortType.Controversial)
        {
            dbPosts = await this.redditCloneUnitOfWork.Posts
                .GetBySubscribedUserOrderedByControversialAsync(dbUser.Id, startDate);
        }
        else if (sortType == PostSortType.Best)
        {
            dbPosts = await this.redditCloneUnitOfWork.Posts
                   .GetBySubscribedUserOrderedByBestAsync(dbUser.Id, startDate);
        }

        var models = this.mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PostConciseViewModel>>(dbPosts);
```

Comment: The question isn't completely clear. Could you maybe edit your post and add a code example showing the `case/switch` you are trying to avoid? It would then be simple for us to tell you how to replace it.

Comment: This is how I try to avoid switch case.The switch was basicly to choose what sorting algoritm to use

Comment: Please add the example. A piece of code is worth a thousand words. I need to see how you intended to supply arguments to the constructors if you were to use switch/case. Does the value for `startDate` come from a user control, for example, or somewhere else?

Comment: Added example and startData will be from a user and I will probably use some enum or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that a user interface must translate the user's needs into a machine-friendly format-- in this case, one of your sorting strategies. Therefore, some code, somewhere, has to look at the user's inputs and decide, probably with an `if` clause, which logic path to take and which type of strategy to instantiate. This aspect of user interface programming is unavoidable.

The safest and most reasonable place to put such code is as close to the user interface controls as possible. There are several reasons for this:

1. By placing the translation code in the user interface module itself, you avoid other code forming dependencies on it.
2. User interface designs tend to change more quickly than business rules, as users find endless novel ways to solve the same problem. When things change at the same time, putting them together in source code eases code and build management, QA and deployment concerns.
3. The ugliness of the code only makes sense in the context of the user interface design, so putting them together makes it easier for future developers to understand what is going on.

As for design patterns, this is one of the few areas where I would let developers write code that looks a little bit spaghetti-ish. The reality of the requirements is that the design is to be optimized for human factors, not machine factors and not architectural elegance. In other words, using `switch/case` is "okay."

That being said, putting `switch/case` around different data retrieval calls is problematic, because typically there is logic around those calls that you'd rather not duplicate. So the strategy pattern is not a bad one. I would suggest a factory pattern that can return a strategy, given a series of user inputs, perhaps passed in a DTO.

At a high level it might look like this:

```
var dto = new GetSortedPostsRequestDto
{
    StartDate = inputForm.StartDatePicker.SelectedDate,
    SortMode = inputForm.GetSelectedSortMode()
};
var strategy = GetSortStrategy(dto);
var results = unitOfWork.GetSortedPosts(strategy);
```

This approach works especially well when the DTO comes from outside your c# code, e.g. if it is was put together by Javascript and sent over via a REST call.

The `GetSortStrategy()` method is where your `case/switch` would exist. While a factory class isn't necessarily out of the question, it can usually be written as a non-generic factory method.

```
ISortStrategy GetSortStrategy(GetSortedPostsRequestDto dto)
{
    switch case dto.SortMode
    {
        case SortMode.New: return new SortByNewStrategy();
        case SortMode.Top: return new SortByTopStrategy();
        case SortMode.Recent: return new SortByRecentStrategy(dto.StartDate);
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Notice this pattern allows you to pass the `startDate` if and only if it applies to the user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the problem is that the DateTime is an implementation detail of one (or some) of the concrete strategy(ies). Therefore, the high level interface should not have this information. If however, you still need this DateTime across multiple strategies, you could create a `BaseTimeDependentPostSortingStrategy` (or whatever name you should choose).

You are using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to provide the DateTime into the method. You can probably inject into the *Constructor* of the types that need timespan instead.

```
public interface ISortPostsStrategy
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId);
}

public abstract class BaseTimeDependentPostSortingStrategy : ISortPostsStrategy
{
    private readonly DateTime _startDate;

    protected BaseTimeDependentPostSortingStrategy(DateTime startDate)
    {
        _startDate = startDate;
    }

    public abstract Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId);
}

public class SortPostsByNew : ISortPostsStrategy
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public SortPostsByNew(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId)
    {
        var dbPosts = await this.unitOfWork.Posts.GetBySubcribedUserOrderedByNewAsync(userId);
        return dbPosts;
    }
}

public class SortPostsByBest : BaseTimeDependentPostSortingStrategy 
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public SortPostsByBest(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, DateTime startDate) : base(startDate)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> SortAsync(string userId)
    {
        var dbPosts = await this.unitOfWork.Posts.GetBySubscribedUserOrderedByBestAsync(userId, _startDate);
        return dbPosts;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: This might not compile, I have not tested it.

If that doesn't answer your question, please provide additional information so that I may help.

Comment: I was thinking to use some factory to get the proper strategy and then to give it to strategy pattern context something like this var strategy = StrategyFactory.GetStrategy(sortType); and then give it to the strategy context and call Order() I added example above for the switch case proble I m trying to avoid

Comment: I wonder is it bad practise to use your code with a factory that will check does the strategy implement BaseTimeDependentPostSortingStrategy and if it does will inject the datetime?